# How environment variables configuration works in dotnet core?

Tags: .net-core

In [Enforce HTTPS with dotnet core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio), there needs to be a port specified for ssl. That port needs to be passed to the application.

See in this [clear way to get a docker container to run dotnet core with ssl](http://parsstudent.com/asp-net-core-2-1-application-in-docker-with-https-enabled/), one of the things we need to do is pass environment variables that the dotnet core application will use; as per [the configuration system details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2#default-configuration).

Also, in the same [Enforce HTTPS with dotnet core article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio), you can pass something like
the `useSetting()`

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSetting("HTTPS_PORT", "443")
            .UseSetting("URLS", "http://+;https://+")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Which is the same as passing `ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443` as an environment variable.

I'm really looking for where on earth I can find clear documentation on what each possible variable can be and what they do.

Comment: Does [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2) not help?

Comment: Thank you! I went too far in the rabbit hole and missed this. Can you please make an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The settings for `WebHost` are well documented.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2)